# How to install apscheduler

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, installation, apscheduler

I would like to use scheduler in my python program however I haven't been able to install it.

I tried with Easy_Install and PIP (neither of which I've used before) and I can't find a link for another method.  I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows Vista

Since I've never used PIP before I had to install that first. After installing pip I went to command prompt, changed to the directory with pip and typed:

C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install apscheduler

It didn't come up with an error so I assumed it installed, however when I run my python program, which includes the line: from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

it states:
ImportError: No module named apscheduler.scheduler

and when I look at the list of installed modules in Idle it's not there.

It's probably something obvious since I don't have a lot of experience in programming yet.

Help would be much appreciated!

sm

---

Hi again,

I got it working finally, in the end I didn't use PIP, in case other people need help this is what I did:

Downloaded the apscheduler  tar.gz file

Downloaded 7-zip, since this can extract tar.gz files on Windows.

Extracted the tar.gz file using 7-zip, I had to do this twice since the first time I clicked extract it extracted to a .tar file (APScheduler-2.1.2.tar), it was necessary to extract this file as well.

Added C:python27\  to the windows path (this is in control panel->system & maintenance->system->advanced system settings->environment variables)

(I also added C:python27\scripts\ to the path, but not sure whether this makes a difference.

Opened command prompt and moved to the folder containing the extracted APScheduler files including the file named setup.py

In my case this was- C:\Python27\APScheduler\APScheduler-2.1.2\APScheduler-2.1.2\

In command prompt typed> python setup.py install

Hopefully this was everything, perhaps one day I'll delete everything and try again to check, but it took quite sometime to get it going so right now I think I'll leave it as is.

Comment: Can you uninstall it and reinstall and then paste the output here?

Comment: Hi, thanks, how do you uninstall?

Comment: .... I tried    >pip uninstall apscheduler              This just waited a few seconds and then another command prompt appeared, which is the same thing that happens when I type            >pip install apscheduler

Comment: Do you mean there was no output??

Comment: You should not install source distributions by simply unpacking them. This works with the wheels but not always for tarballs. The tarballs often contain extra files that are not supposed to be installed.

Comment: Yep, no output when installing with PIP, whereas when I did it the other way by unzipping and installing tar.gz manually Command Prompt came up with a list of what was installing. I suspect PIP wasn't actually installing anything..... ok, thanks, I couldn't work out how to install the whl file it looked complicated.  If I could get PIP or whl install working that would be better.  It's probably a problem with PIP or my install method not APScheduler since I haven't successfully installed anything with PIP yet.

Comment: `pip install` worked for me.  The problem is that you have gotten the newest version, and you have to import `BackgroundScheduler` and make corresponding changes, this is in the official documentation:
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html